# Facebook SDK comment on post iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, facebook-ios-sdk

As I understand, to comment on a post. I need the id of the post. But for my case, I want to know the post id before posting the message. Is this possible? Right now I use FBRequestConnection to post a message to the wall. But I want the id to be included in the message, because there will be an url scheme to open my app.

Comment: "Is this possible?" - not quite. The post ID is created by the server after it has successfully processed the request.

Comment: If this isn't possible I am thinking that the only way to do it would be to create 2 separate posts. And add the url scheme on the second one which got the id of the first one. Maybe this would be a possible solution?